# How to retrieve data using Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am a newbie to LINQ , so obviously facing difficulty in writing queries.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int cid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Orderid { get; set; }
    public int customerid { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer(){cid=1,FirstName="Avinash",LastName="Kothamasu",City="Chennai"},
        new Customer(){cid=2,FirstName="Abhiram",LastName="Kumar",City="Chennai"},
        new Customer{cid=3,FirstName="Balu",LastName="Chinna",City="Chennai"},
        new Customer{cid=4,FirstName="Sai",LastName="Kothamasu",City="Bhimavaram"},
        new Customer{cid=5,FirstName="Harshita",LastName="Kothamasu",City="Bhimarvarm"},
        new Customer{cid=6,FirstName="Mounika",LastName="Kothamasu",City="Guntur"}
    };

    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order(){Orderid=11,customerid=1,Quantity=20},
        new Order(){Orderid=111,customerid=1,Quantity=10},
        new Order(){Orderid=22,customerid=2,Quantity=15},
        new Order(){Orderid=222,customerid=2,Quantity=8},
        new Order(){Orderid=22222,customerid=2,Quantity=50},
        new Order(){Orderid=33,customerid=3,Quantity=10},
        new Order(){Orderid=333,customerid=3,Quantity=5},
        new Order(){Orderid=44,customerid=4,Quantity=4},
        new Order(){Orderid=55,customerid=5,Quantity=1},
        new Order(){Orderid=66,customerid=6,Quantity=2}
    };

    var OrderListforCustomers = from c in customerList
                                join o in orderList on
                                c.cid equals o.customerid
                                where o.Quantity > 1 && o.Quantity <= 50
                                group new { c, o } by new { o.customerid, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.City } into customergroups
                                orderby customergroups.Key.customerid
                                select new
                                {
                                    CustomerID = customergroups.Key.customerid,
                                    CustomerName = customergroups.Key.FirstName.ToUpper() + " , " + customergroups.Key.LastName.ToUpper(),
                                    City = customergroups.Key.City,
                                    MaximumQuantityCount = customergroups.Select(x=>x.o).Max(x=>x.Quantity),
                                                *OrderIDwithMaxQuanCount=customergroups.Select(x=>x.o.Orderid).Where();*
                                };

    Console.Write("CID" + " || ");
    Console.Write("CustomerName" + " || ");
    Console.Write("City" + " | ");
    Console.Write("MaximumQuantityCount" + " || ");
    Console.Write("OrderIDwithMaxCount");
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

    foreach (var custgroup in OrderListforCustomers)
    {
        Console.Write(custgroup.CustomerID + " || ");
        Console.Write(custgroup.CustomerName + " || ");
        Console.Write(custgroup.City + " || ");
        Console.Write(custgroup.MaximumQuantityCount + " || ");
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here, What i am trying to do is print the customer details along with order details with some condidtions.

**I need to print the orderid of a customer that has maxmimum quantity**

**I was able to retieve the MaxOrderCount for a Particular customer but was not able to fetch the order id having maximum quantity**

In the query, last line in the select clause , i was facing some difficulty on how to write

Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order first and then select like this:

```
 OrderIDwithMaxQuanCount=customergroups.OrderByDescending(x => x.o.Quantity)
                                       .Select(x => x.o.Orderid).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: @Aducci...Worked as a Charm..have been breaking my head for long time..Thanks

Comment: ..I have small doubt here..can i order by Quantity in the order by clause below the group by clause ??

Comment: @AvinashKothamasu, I do not follow...I would create another question and I might be able to help

Comment: @Aducci..here is link for new question,,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883313/is-it-possible-to-order-by-column-which-is-not-present-in-groupby