# Is it possible to order by column which is not present in groupby?

Tags: c#, linq

For example , i have a query like this:

```
var data= from c in customers
          join o in orders
          on c.id=o.id
         group new { c, o } by new { o.customerid, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.City } into customergroups
         orderby customergroup.select(x=>x.o.quantity)
```

But, it is giving me empty result set..

Please suggest..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to order your groups by anything, as long as the expression produces a comparable object. For example, you could order by the *minimum* or the *maximum* quantity <sup>*</sup>, but not by just quantity, because there may be many different quantities in a group.

```
var data= from c in customers
      join o in orders
      on c.id=o.id
     group new { c, o } by new { o.customerid, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.City } into customergroups
     orderby customergroup.Max(x=>x.o.quantity);
```

<sup>*</sup> You could also use `First(x=>x.o.quantity)` or `Last(x=>x.o.quantity)`, but the order would be arbitrary.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight..it really is an enlightening answeer for me..Fantastic..I am finding some great answers for LINQ in SO..Thank you very much..